# Why don't cards that exile themselves go to the graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Calamity's Wake](https://media.wizards.com/2022/bro/en_nMCrn3lEOL.png) is a card from the Brothers' War set that has the text “Exile Calamity's Wake.” at the end of it.

The clear intention of this card is that after it is cast, it goes to exile instead of the graveyard. However, I'm curious about the wording because it isn't worded as a replacement effect, which means there doesn't seem to be anything stopping this card from going to the graveyard as part of resolution.

The relevant comprehensive rules are:

> 608.2k If an instant spell, sorcery spell, or ability that can legally resolve leaves the stack once it starts to resolve, it will continue
> to resolve fully.
>
> 608.2m As the final part of an instant or sorcery spell’s resolution, the spell is put into its owner’s graveyard. As the final part of an
> ability’s resolution, the ability is removed from the stack and ceases
> to exist.

These two rules together suggest to me that Calamity's Wake exiles itself, continues resolving, then moves to the final steps of resolution which according to 608.2m moves the spell to the owner's graveyard. Nothing about 608.2m looks like it requires the spell to currently be on the stack to happen.

Is there any other comprehensive rule that clears up how a spell exiling itself is supposed to behave? I know how it's clearly meant to work, but I'm just looking for the justification from the comprehensive rules.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is a consequence of CR 400.7

> An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence.

and the "Golden Rule" 101.3:

> Any part of an instruction that’s impossible to perform is ignored. (In many cases the card will specify consequences for this; if it doesn’t, there’s no effect.)

As you note, 608.2k means that we do the following things in order:

1. "Exile all graveyards": no problem here.
2. "Players can't cast noncreature spells this turn": no problem here.
3. "Exile Calamity's Wake": this moves the spell from the stack to the exile zone. As per 400.7, the object in exile is unrelated to the object on the stack so any effects which would have applied to the spell do not apply to this object.

If there were further text on Calamity's Wake, we would continue to follow those instructions as per 608.2k. There isn't, so we don't need to worry about that here.

We now come to 608.2m; this instructs us to put the spell into the owner's graveyard. We can't do this, because the spell doesn't exist any more, so we apply the golden rule. The card (or rules in this case) don't specify a consequence for this so there is no effect.

The spell has now finished resolving, and there is an object in exile called "Calamity's Wake". The game continues as usual by checking state-based actions.

(All rules quotes from the [2022-10-07 Comprehensive Rules](https://media.wizards.com/2022/downloads/Comprehensive%20Rules%2020221007.pdf))

Comment: preventing confusion is also why spells that exile themselves always have the self-exile instruction as the last one on the card. Helps to avoid problems with people not familiar with CR minutiae.

Comment: @Andrew Absolutely. I really only brought 608.2k into it because the OP mentioned it in the question.

Comment: While I trust you that this is the official justification for this behaviour, I can't help but be unsatisfied with it, purely because 400.7 seems very vague. The text on 608.2m doesn't sound like it *requires* memory of the original spell cast. By 608.2k the spell continues resolving after it changes zone. It may not remember how it got there, but it IS a spell, and it IS resolving. And if it's a spell that's resolving, after resolution 608.2m states that it goes to a graveyard. This is far from clear to me

Comment: I am accepting however, as again, I trust this is the official justification

Comment: @Cruncher It is not a spell when it is in exile.  112.1 "A Spell is a card on the stack..."

Comment: @Cruncher Read rule 400.7 as meaning something effectively like this: "If an object would move to a different zone, run it through a shredder, burn it to ash, and disperse the ashes to the wind. Separately, as a *nominally unrelated* action, get a card (or whatever) with the same name and put it into the other zone." The card that ends up in exile *is not the spell that just resolved*. It is a new object that is (as far as the rules are concerned) completely unrelated to the spell.

Comment: What about 400.7h "If an effect causes an object to move to a public zone, other parts of that effect can find that object." ?

Comment: One way of looking at it is that when rule 608.2k says that "it will continue to resolve fully", you're not continuing to resolve the object that the spell has now become in some other zone, but rather the spell object that *existed* up to the point that it was exiled. This is similar to how last known information is handled in rule 608.2h.

Comment: @Taemyr If the card isn't a spell anymore then *what* is resolving? What is the "it" in 608.2k referring to?

Comment: @Cruncher "It" in 608.2k refers to the spell on the stack.  There might have been a semantic issue here if the rules had been phrased "once the spell is moved to a different zone it will continue to resolve".  But given that the phrasing talks about what happens as the spell is moved to a different zone it has not been moved yet and so there is no issue.